# data source name not found or no default driver specified in vba

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am trying to connect mysql database using vba script but unfortunately i am getting an error  "data source name not found or no default driver specified "

This is the code

```vb
Sub connection()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
    Dim server_name As String
    Dim database_name As String
    Dim user_id As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim op As Long

    server_name = "127.0.0.1" ' 
    database_name = "test" 'database  name 
    user_id = "root" '  user ID 
    password = "" '  password 

    Set conn = New ADODB.connection
    conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
      "SERVER=server_name;" & _
      "DATABASE=database_name;" & _
      "USER=user_id;" & _
      "PASSWORD=password;" & _
      "option=3" 'getting error at this point
End Sub
```

Please help me with that
I have also tested connection odbc and it works fine.I have 5.3 odbc driver
thanks in advance

Comment: You will want `"SERVER=" & server_name & ";" & _` `"DATABASE=" & database_name & ";" & _` `"USER=" & user_id & ";" & _` `"PASSWORD=" & password & ";" & _` `"option=3"` Not sure about the rest...

Answer (score 0):

The error message means one of a few different things:

1. You are referencing the driver incorrectly in your connection string, check to make sure that the driver name you're using is correct.
2. You're trying to reference a 32-bit driver from 64-bit VB or vice versa, ensure the bitnesses match.
3. The driver is installed incorrectly, are you able to create a DSN or connect via a different application such as Excel?